# How to create cloudwatch alarm before there is data for metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to create a cloudwatch alarm for the sns metric `NumberOfMessagesPublished` on a new sns topic.  If I attempt to do this before I trigger the topic (and there is no data for it) then the option to create an alarm does not exist in the web console.

How can I do this with the web console? Is using a cli tool the only option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed that too -- you cannot select a metric until the data has been sent to CloudWatch.

I suspect that CloudWatch actually doesn't have any visibility into metrics until they are sent from the originating service into CloudWatch. Thus, it can't populate the console because it doesn't know what data will be sent. That would be a nice, loosely-coupled design.

My experiments show that it **is** possible create an alarm via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on metrics that do not exist -- even within the EC2 namespace. That's the way to go!

Comment: `aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --alarm-name <alarm name> --metric-name <metric name> --namespace <namespace> --statistic Sum --period 60 --threshold 5  --comparison-operator GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold --dimensions "Name=<dimension name>,Value=<dimension value>" --evaluation-periods 1 --alarm-actions <SNS ARN>`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Cloudformation. It is the best way to create resources stack in AWS and overall you can easily experiment with it and delete everything when you are done. Here there is a sample application that uses Cloudformation and Cloudwatch https://github.com/awslabs/cloudwatch-dashboards-cloudformation-sample

Answer (score 0):

The manual solution I went with was to create the sns topic and then use the `Publish to topic` option in the sns menu to send out a test message to my subscribers.  This creates a set of notifications without the need to set off the cloudwatch rule.  After this the option appears in the cloudwatch alarm creation menu.

The other CLI options would be better for automation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The [AWS Official Documentation answers your question](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html). Just to quote the relevant lines:

> You can create an alarm for a custom metric before you've created that custom metric. For the alarm to be valid, you must include all of the dimensions for the custom metric in addition to the metric namespace and metric name in the alarm definition.